# Do I need to switch javac to version 7?

Tags: linux, java-7

I've setup Java 7 at `/usr/bin/java` in ubuntu 12.04 to replace the default which is Java 6.

I have done the same for `/usr/bin/javaws`.

Do I also need to do this for `/usr/bin/javac` in order to be fully consistent?  For some reason `/usr/bin/javac` does not exist by default.  Running `javac -verion` only produces a suggestion that I use `apt-get` to install it but hesitate to jump to the conclusion that it is not installed.  Of course if I use `javac` I would want to be consistent and have version 7, but I'm not sure if I use `javac`.

I create `.jar` files using Eclipse and I'm not sure what goes on inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own Java compiler - it does not use javac. So if your package manager tells you that you don't have javac installed, you probably don't - Eclipse wouldn't care whether you have javac installed or not. It will also be unaffected by which version of javac you have installed because, as I said, it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). It doesn't contain the Java compiler (javac). The compiler is only part of a Java Development Kit (JDK) installation.

Eclipse comes with its own JDK and/or a private JRE. While using Eclipse for Java Developers, you can choose the JDK you want to use to compiler your projects. So, you don't need to update Eclipse's JRE either.

Comment: Actually I installed the JDK so I do have `javac` if I care to use it. I suppose then, I should have installed the JRE instead since apparently I don't need the JDK.  This has me wondering if my deployment should have Eclipse's JRE just to be perfectly safe and how am I going get the JRE from Eclipse.

Comment: Only install a JDK if you're doing Java development. You shouldn't touch Eclipse's JRE... it's not meant to be used as the default Java version (for example, I don't recall mine being subject to the same Java update notifications).